# How to selectively copy details from a file and paste them into a new file?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a file containing my personal details (.txt). How can I via the terminal copy only a few details from the file and put those into a new `.txt` file?

For example, if this is the content of the file:

```
name : farah age : 23 phone number : 0123 education : degree
```

how can I copy only age and phone number and output those to a new `.txt` file?

Comment: It depends on what you want copied to the new file.  Do you want the first few lines, the last few, lines containing a string, not containing a string, lines between two strings?  There are tools to do all these, but we need to know what you wish to do.

Answer (score 7):

There are several ways to do this. If your file has some known structure, you can use `grep`. The `grep` command searches a file for a specific phrase and returns lines that match that phrase. So if your file looks like

> Name: Sally
>
> Date of Birth: 7.31.76
>
> Address: 1234 Main St.
>
> SSN: 123-45-6789

you can run `grep Name info.txt` and it will return `Name: Sally`. You can then [redirect](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) the output to another file. So calling

`grep Name info.txt > info2.txt`

will output the line to the new file info2.txt. If you want to append new lines, you can do

`grep Address info.txt >> info2.txt`

otherwise the file will be overwritten.

You could also learn to use a command line text editor like [vim.](http://www.vim.org/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [grep](http://man.cx/grep) to search for a [regular expression](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Regular_expression) in *details.txt* and redirect the result to the new file.

If all the lines you want to copy have something in common the other lines don't you can use  :

```
grep "string in common" details.txt > new.txt
```

If not you will have to search for each line you want to copy, still using grep, and append them to *new.txt* using `>>` in stead of `>`.

Answer (score 2):

The file you showed has all the details on one line:

```
name : farah age : 23 phone number : 0123 education : degree
```

I have assumed that you can hard-code `age :` etc into the command, but the text following it will vary, and that the details may not be in the given order or be contiguous.

You can extract parts of the line with `grep`'s `-o` flag. This prints only the matched part, rather than the whole line.

If you want to include the `age :` and `phone number :` parts, you can either use the `-e` flag to specify multiple matches, or alternation.

```
$ grep -oe 'age : [^ ]*' -e 'phone number : [^ ]*' file
age : 23
phone number : 0123
```

The expression `[^ ]*` means any number of characters that are not a space, so it matches characters after `age :`  up to the next space.

Replace `file` with the name of the file that contains your details. You may write the new file by redirecting the output to a new file with the `>` operator, like this:

```
grep -oe 'age : [^ ]*' -e 'phone number : [^ ]*' file > outfile
```

When you do that, you won't see any output. You should check the output first, then add redirection.

Here's the example with alternation. We use the `-E` flag to tell `grep` to use extended regex. The syntax is `(pattern1|pattern2)` - this matches `pattern1` and/or `pattern2`. If either is found, it will be printed (regardless of whether the other is found or not). I'm now using `+` meaning at least one of the preceding character, instead of `*` meaning zero or more of the preceding character. In this context, they both work equally well.

```
$ grep -Eo '(age : [^ ]+|phone number : [^ ]+)' file
age : 23 
phone number : 0123
```

If you want to omit the `age :` and `phone number:` parts, you can use the `-P` flag to ask `grep` to use Perl-compatible regular expressions. This supports alternation, and also a way of matching text *after* a given pattern:

```
$ grep -Po '(age : \K[^ ]+|phone number : \K[^ ]+)' file
23
0123
```

If you want to format the text differently, you can use `sed`, for example:

```
$ sed -r 's/.*(age) : ([^ ]*).*(phone number) : ([^ ]*).*/\1:\2 | \3:\4/' file
age:23 | phone number:0123
```

This depends on `age` coming before `phone number`, so adjust accordingly if that's not the case. If you can't rely on the order, you can use this very convoluted command:

```
$ sed -r 's/(.*)(phone number : [^ ]+)(.*) .*/\2 \1\4/; s/(phone number) : ([^ ]+) .*(age) : ([^ ]+).*/\1: \2 | \3: \4/' file
phone number: 0123 | age: 23
```

This rearranges the line so that the `phone number :` section comes first on every line, then does a second replacement to select the desired details. I owe the technique used here to [this answer by muru](https://askubuntu.com/questions/867664/i-need-to-use-sed-awk-to-get-desired-output/867822#867822).

#### Notes on `sed` commands not covered by previous explanations

- `-r` use extended regex for more readable commands (GNU `sed` understands `-E` with the same meaning)
- `s/old/new/` replace `old` with `new`
- `(pattern)` saves `pattern` to reference later, with `\1` or `\2` etc (corresponding to the left-to-right order in which the capture groups occur - note that `sed` will only hold up to 7 of these!).
- `.` any character, therefore `.*` represents any number of any characters.
- `;` separates commands, as in the shell.

Answer (score 1):

There are also editors which work in the terminal, e.g. nano, vi and emacs.

If you are using a graphical user interface on your local machine and a terminal on a remote machine, you can also use the mouse to copy and paste from one terminal window/tab to a second one.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming input file `details.txt` contains:

```
name: farah
age: 23
phone number: 0123
education: degree
```

you can select lines "name" and "phone" by extended grep and redirect output to new.txt:

```
grep -E "age:|phone number:" details.txt > new.txt
```

This will produce new.txt with:

```
age: 23
phone number: 0123
```

**How it works:**

Grep prints only matched lines. The `-E` options enabled extended regexp which gives you possibility to use `|` (alternative). Remember to quote whole pattern, so `|` will be interpreted by grep. Otherwise shell will try to interpret. You don't want this here.