# I need to use sed/awk to get desired output

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed, awk

```
Order:479959,60=20130624-09:45:02.046|35=D|11=884|38=723|21=1|1=30532|10=085|59=0|114=Y|56=MBT|40=1|43=Y|100=MBTX|55=/GCQ3|49=11342|54=1|8=FIX.4.4|34=388|553=2453|9=205|52=20130624-09:45:02.046|

Order:24780,100=MBTX|43=Y|40=1|34=388|553=2453|52=2013062409:45:02.046|9=205|49=11342|54=1|8=FIX.4.4|55=/GCQ3|11=405|35=D|60=20130624-09:45:02.046|56=MBT|59=0|114=Y|10=085|21=1|38=470|1=30532|

Order:799794,55=/GCQ3|49=11342|54=1|8=FIX.4.4|34=388|553=2453|9=205|52=2013062409:45:02.046|40=1|43=Y|100=MBTX|38=350|21=1|1=30532|10=085|59=0|114=Y|56=MBT|60=20130624-09:45:02.046|35=D|11=216|

Order:72896,11=735|35=D|60=2013062409:45:02.046|56=MBT|59=0|114=Y|10=085|1=30532|38=17|21=1|100=MBTX|43=Y|40=1|553=2453|9=205|52=20130624-09:45:02.046|34=388|8=FIX.4.4|54=1|49=11342|55=/GCQ3|
```

I want to get the number after `38=` and the number after `11=` which should be renamed `Clientid`

The output should be:-

```
Orderid-479959 38= 723 Clientid=884
Orderid-24780 38= 470 Clientid=405
Orderid-799794 38= 350 Clientid=216
Orderid-72896 38= 17 Clientid=735
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Take a minute to describe how you arrived at this "desired output" which is missing a row

Comment: OP added missing line and I think I made it clear enough...

Comment: @Zanna of course you did. Please add an explanation to my answer too.

Comment: Cross-posted: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/334572/70524

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
sed -nr 's/Order:([0-9]+),.*[,\|]38=([0-9]+)[,\|].*/Orderid-\1 38= \2/p' file | tee file2
```

Then

```
sed -nr 's/.*[,\|]11=([0-9]+)[,\|].*/Clientid=\1/p' file | tee file3
```

Then

```
paste -d ' ' file2 file3
```

You get your output on stdout - redirect as you please.

I can't get it in one line (although [someone obviously can](https://askubuntu.com/a/867822/527764)) since the `11=` and `38=` fields could be in either order - I have to read the file twice. You could roll it into a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -nr 's/Order:([0-9]+),.*[,\|]38=([0-9]+)[,\|].*/Orderid-\1 38= \2/p' "$1" > file2
sed -nr 's/.*[,\|]11=([0-9]+)[,\|].*/Clientid=\1/p' "$1" > file3
paste -d ' ' file2 file3 > outfile
rm file2 file3
```

(this cleans up the files we write in the process and writes the final output to a file `outfile`)

#### Usage:

- paste the script into an empty file and save it
- give it execute permission: `chmod u+x script`
- run it with the name of your input file as argument: `./script file`
- change `file2` and `file3` in the script if you have existing files with those names in the current directory!

#### Explanation

- `s/old/new` replace `old` with `new`
- `-r` use ERE
- `-n` don't print until we ask (this is just going to take out empty lines)
- `[,\|]` match `,` OR literal `|`
- `([0-9]+)` some digits to save for later
- `\1` backreference to saved pattern
- `tee` write to a file and print to stdout too so you can check it
- `> somefile` redirect output to `somefile` instead of stdout
- `paste -d ' ' file2 file3` paste columns of file3 after columns of file2 using a space as delimiter.
- `rm file2 file3` delete file2 and file3

Comment: is it possible to do it with one command?

Comment: @Sonal I can't figure out a single command, because the `11=` field and `38=` field could occur in either order. Because of this, we have to read the file twice. You can make it into a script though, I will do that for you...

Answer (score 4):

## Using awk

Assuming your data is in a file called `data.txt`, create a file called `script.awk` and give it the following contents:

```
BEGIN { FS="[,|]" }
NF > 0 {
  for(i=1; i <= NF; i++) {
    split($i, f, "[:=]")
    map[f[1]] = f[2]
  }
  printf "Orderid-%s 38= %s Clientid=%s\n", map["Order"], map[38], map[11]
}
```

Then execute the following command to process the data and get output.

```
awk -f script.awk < data.txt
```

## See also

- [Getting started with `awk`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getting-Started.html#Getting-Started)
- [`BEGIN` pattern](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Field-Separators.html#index-BEGIN-pattern)
- [Associative arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Array-Intro.html#index-arrays_002c-associative)
- [`split` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#index-split_0028_0029-function)
- [`printf` statement](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Printf.html#Printf)
- [`NF` variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Fields.html#index-NF-variable)
- [`FS` variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Field-Separators.html#index-FS-variable)

In the above code, the `map` variable is an associative array.  I called it map because it's typically called a map in other languages (HashMap in Java, Hash in Ruby, or Dictionary in Python).

Comment: Sure, I misunderstood the data.  I know a better way.

Comment: Added a few lines to process the other part of the map which was missing.

Comment: Fixed, I had a typo transcribing (programming from my iPad).

Comment: I added some links to documentation so you can do some additional reading.

Comment: Since this GNU awk, you can use `[|,]` as the `FS` so that it splits on both `,` and `|` - saves a `split`, which is not much, I suppose.

Comment: muru Actually your suggestion helps me to greatly improve the script.

Answer (score 3):

One liners aren't always nice:

```
$ sed 's/[|,]\(11=[^|]*\).*\(|38=[^|]*|\).*/\2\1|/; s/Order:\([0-9]*\).*|38=\([0-9]*\).*|11=\([0-9]*\)|.*/Orderid-\1 38= \2 Clientid=\3/' foo
Orderid-479959 38= 723 Clientid=884
Orderid-24780 38= 470 Clientid=405
Orderid-799794 38= 350 Clientid=216
Orderid-72896 38= 17 Clientid=735
```

#### Explanation

- `s/old/new/` replace `old` with `new`
- `[|,]` match `|` or `,`
- `\(11=[^|]*\)` match any number of any characters except `|` after `11=` and save `11=whatever` for later use as `\1`
- `.*` any number of any characters
- `\(|38=[^|]*|\)` save `|38=whatever|` for later use as `\2`
- `\2\1|` backreferences in replacement (this makes the fields consistent so we can deal with them in the next command)
- `;` separates commands, like in the shell
- `Order:\([0-9]*\).*|38=\([0-9]*\).*|11=\([0-9]*\)|.*` match this pattern (now we've cleaned it up) saving the parts we want to reuse in `\(parentheses\)` again
- `Orderid-\1 38= \2 Clientid=\3` replacement with `\1` `\2` and `\3` backreferences to the numbers we saved with `\(\)`

Comment: @Zanna tiny correction - `\(11=[^|]*\)` isn't excluding `,` - the example input doesn't contain any such instance, so I didn't include that case.

Comment: haha idk where I read that comma in the expression!

Answer (score 0):

#### Perl solution:

As one-liner:

```
perl -a -F'[:|,]' -lne  'next if $_ =~ /^$/;printf("%sid-%s ",$F[0],$F[1]);foreach(@F){$t=$_ if $_ =~ "38=";$id=$_ if $_ =~ "11="};$id =~s/11=//;printf("%s Clientid=%s\n",$t,$id)' input.txt
```

Or as script:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $fh,'<',$ARGV[0]) or die $!;

while(my $line = <$fh>){
    next if $line =~ /^$/;
    my @words  = split /[:|,]/,$line;
    printf("%sid-%s ",$words[0],$words[1]);
    my $t;
    my $id;
    foreach my $word (@words){
        $t = $word if $word =~ "38=";
        $id=$word if     $word =~ "11=";
        $id =~ s/11=// if length($id);
    }
    printf("%s Clientid=%s\n", $t ,$id);
}
close($fh) or die $!;
```

Test results:

```
$ ./parse_orders.pl ./input.txt                                                                                          
Orderid-479959 38=723 Clientid=884
Orderid-24780 38=470 Clientid=405
Orderid-799794 38=350 Clientid=216
Orderid-72896 38=17 Clientid=735
```