# AWK print from pattern to pattern

Tags: text-processing, awk

file:

```
string1 string2 string3 string4 string5 string6  
string3 string1 string2 string4 string5 string6  
string6 string3 string2 string4 string1 string5
```

expectation:

```
string2 string3 string4 string5  
string2 string4 string5  
string2 string4 string1 string5
```

Match pattern=`string1`
How to print match lines but only from `string2` to `string5` with `awk` ?

Unfortunately this is not processing in line :

```
 awk '/string2/,/string5/' file
```

Let's assume there are few long lines with `string2` and `string5` in different places.

Comment: We don't do homework for you.

Comment: @waltinator this is not a homework. Can't find solution. Incredible how easy is to judge :)

Comment: OK, you edited the question, but you only added same comment that you posted on steeldrivers answer. This doesn't clarify at all. Please post an example of file you are working with, and the output that you want to see.   See this post for example: http://askubuntu.com/q/867664/295286  User shows what they have, and what they want command to output

Comment: @Serg it should be clear now

Comment: Answer updated. Please review

Comment: Why `awk`? This seems like a simple job for `sed`: `sed 's/.*\(string2.*string5\).*/\1/'`

Comment: What's that about string1 though? You only want lines with that? If so your example does not help.

Answer (score 3):

You can use awk's `index` and `match` functions e.g.

```
awk 'match($0,/string5/) {
  START2 = index($0,"string2");
  print substr($0,START2,RSTART+RLENGTH-START2)
}' file
```

Ex.

```
$ mawk 'match($0,/string5/) {
  START2 = index($0,"string2");
  print substr($0,START2,RSTART+RLENGTH-START2)
}' file
string2 string3 string4 string5
string2 string4 string5
string2 string4 string1 string5
```

Note this assumes that `string2` will exist in every line in which `string5` exists - if that's not the case, you will need to check the value of `index($0,"string2")` and act accordingly.

Comment: Can't do it. Let's assume there are few  long lines with string2 and string5 in different places.

Comment: @EdiD OK, please clarify your question.  You need to post an actual example of text you are using so that we can  work with something. Otherwise, your question is unclear. If you keep changing requirements as you go, we can't help you

Comment: @Serg  question edited.

Comment: @steeldriver OP edited his question, see updated input and output examples

Answer (score 3):

Effectively,what you want to do is iterate over each field, and "enable" printing with a variable if result is found. Thus, what you need is a flag variable and for loop:

```
$ cat file.txt
string1 string2 string3 string4 string5 string6
string3 string1 string2 string4 string5 string6
string6 string3 string2 string4 string1 string5

$ awk '{flag=0;for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ if($i=="string2") flag=1; if($i=="string6") flag=0;  if(flag)printf "%s%s",$i,FS;};print"";}' file.txt  
string2 string3 string4 string5 
string2 string4 string5 
string2 string4 string1 string5
```

What happens here is that the whole code block will run for each line. On each line we are iterating from first field to last. Initially we set flag variable to 0, then proceed to examine each field. If field contains the desired "string2" , the flag will be set to 1, and if it is "string6" (which is the one when we want to stop) - flag will be set to 0; finally, if statement will check if flag is set and print the current field appended with field separator (represented by FS variable). After all has been printed we also insert new-line via `print ""` command.

In case where you have lines without match, the above command will print blank lines. You can mitigate that via adding search pattern, which will limit code-block execution only when there is pattern found in string:

```
$ cat file.txt
string1 string2 string3 string4 string5 string6
blah blah
string3 string1 string2 string4 string5 string6
string6 string3 string2 string4 string1 string5

$ awk '$0~"string2"{flag=0;for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ if($i=="string2") flag=1;  if(flag)printf "%s%s",$i,FS;};print"";}' file.txt
string2 string3 string4 string5 string6 
string2 string4 string5 string6 
string2 string4 string1 string5
```

Alternatively, we can use an extra variable with same result:

```
$ awk '{j=0;f=0;for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i=="string2"){j=1;f=1};if(f)printf "%s%s",$i,FS;};if(j)print"";}' file.txt        
string2 string3 string4 string5 string6 
string2 string4 string5 string6 
string2 string4 string1 string5
```

Comment: Almost but output should be without string6

Comment: @EdiD yes, i noticed that. Will edit in a minute

Comment: Could you also make some explanation about printf part.

Comment: +1 It works but prints empty lines before match.

Comment: @EdiD do you have lines where there is no `"string2"` ?

Comment: Yes there are empty lines when there is no string2

Answer (score 2):

First, you only keep lines containing `string2` and `string5` in that particular order (pattern in line 1). All you have to do next is strip everything before `string2` and everything after `string5` (lines 2 and 3) and finally print what remains.

```
awk '/string2 .* string5/ {
    sub(/^.*string2/, "string2", $0);
    sub(/string5.*$/, "string5", $0);
    print $0;
}'
```

Comment: It also works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Using grep:

```
grep -Po '\bstring2.*string5\b' file.txt
```